# JavaFX how to start playing song on startup

Tags: java, url, javafx, media-player

I wanna make a simple app that automatically plays a song from URL when started. I know how to play a song on button press using mediaPlayer, but i dont know how to play it automatically ?

This is my method for `initPlayer` that i use inside of a `playButtonFired` method in my `Controller` class:

```
public void startup(){
    String URL="http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/javafx/JavaRap_Audio.mp4";
    initPlayer(URL);
}


private  void initPlayer(String uri)
{

    if(uri==null)
    {
        return;

    }
    Media media = new Media(uri);
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
    mediaPlayer.setOnReady(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            enableControls();
        }
    });
```

And this is my main class:

```
public class MainGui extends Application  {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    Parent root = null;

    try {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MediaPlayer.fxml"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);


}
```

Comment: add your code which starts to play the song inside the `public void start(Stage primaryStage)` function of JavaFX. (`mediaPlayer.play()` starts playing a song)

Comment: Okay, but the method "public void start(Stage primaryStage)" is placed in another class (a JavaFX main class), and the code above is placed in my controller class. So I cant use the initPlayer(String uri) method in there.

Comment: You can solve this by holding a reference to your controller in the Main class, or (which I would prefer myself) just create a `public static void startup()` function in your Controller and call it from the JavaFX start function. That way you can add everything that should be done on startup inside your new function in your controller. (this is cleaner than holding x references in the Main class)

Comment: I think i understand. I edited my original post to show you my code. But the problem is the same, i cant call the `public static void startup()` method from my main class :(

Comment: Your updated code is missing the `static` from `public static void startup()`. Yours reads: `public void startup()`. Add it and call it from your main class with `Controller.startup();`, preferably below `primaryStage.show();`.

Comment: Thanks !! What i was simply using `startup()` instead of `Controller.startup()`.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. I added this as an answer so you can accept it.

Comment: Why not just put the code in the controller's `initialize()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your code which starts to play the song inside the `public void start(Stage primaryStage)` function of JavaFX. (`mediaPlayer.play()` starts playing a song)

**EDIT:**

Your updated code is missing the `static` from `public static void startup()`. Yours reads: `public void startup()`. Add it and call it from your main class with `Controller.startup();`, preferably below `primaryStage.show()`;